# Decimal. Parse string, postfixed by a minus sign

Tags: c#

```
decimal decimalVal;
Decimal.TryParse("123-", out decimalVal);
Console.WriteLine(decimalVal); // -123
```

Why do "123-" string parsed this way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Decimal.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) parses the input with [NumberStyles.Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) by default. [NumberStyles.Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) includes [NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx).

> **Decimal.TryParse Method (String, Decimal)**
>
> [...]
> Parameter s is interpreted using the NumberStyles.Number style.
> [...]

> **Number**   
> Indicates that the AllowLeadingWhite, AllowTrailingWhite, AllowLeadingSign, AllowTrailingSign, AllowDecimalPoint, and AllowThousands styles are used. This is a composite number style.
>
> **AllowTrailingSign**  
> Indicates that the numeric string can have a trailing sign. Valid trailing sign characters are determined by the NumberFormatInfo.PositiveSign and NumberFormatInfo.NegativeSign properties.

Answer (score 1):

NumberStyles.Number enumerator is used by default:

Indicates that the AllowLeadingWhite, AllowTrailingWhite, AllowLeadingSign, AllowTrailingSign, AllowDecimalPoint, and AllowThousands styles are used. This is a composite number style

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The NumberNegativePattern is only used for string output, but ignored when parsing.
For parsing, another parameter is used: `NumberStyles`.

`Convert.ChangeType` routes to `decimal.Parse` in your example, so if you directly used the correct overload, you can specify to not allow a trailing sign:

```
var result = decimal.Parse("123-", NumberStyles.Number & ~NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign); // will throw an exception
```

Comment: or use `NumberStyles.Float` or `NumberStyles.Integer`

Answer (score 0):

This is an accepted format for `Decimal.Parse`.  The `style` option to the `Parse` method allows for leading and trailing signs.

Read more:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91fwbcsb.aspx